# Is it possible to release a NFT collection then later mint more from the same collection?

Tags: metaplex, nft, sugar

If I wanted to release 1k NFTs, then if they sell out release more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that question depends on how you will be creating these NFTs.

**Editions:**

If the NFTs are all the same you could use an open Edition and first print 1k Editions and later on add more.

**Candy machine:**
If you are creating normal NFTs and want to sell them you could use sugar to create a candy machine and do one of the following:

- Create the CMv2 for x thousand > 1k NFTs and use end settings and set them to 1000 to first just sell 1k, then later update the endsettings to be able to sell more

```
"endSettings": {
  "endSettingType": "Amount",
  "number": 1000
   }
```

- Or first create a CMv2 with 1k NFTs and sell out. As soon as you need more NFTs create a new Candy machine. Before selling the first NFT use `sugar collection set <COLLECTION MINT ID>` to set the candy machine to the same collection as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you have the collection NFT/Parent NFT for your Collection.If you are going to use Candy Machine then you have to setup multiple Candy Machines because once you have specified the size than more NFT metadata cannot be added in it. So in this case you need to have 2 Candy Machines one for the initial 1K NFTs and later on a different Candy Machine. The Main Thing is all your NFT should be pointing to the same Collection NFT.